# How to determine if a string is a valid Java expression in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, expression

I want to determine whether a given string is a valid Java expression (according to Java's syntax).

For example:

```
object.apply()
x == 2
(x != null) && x.alive
```

Are all valid expressions in Java.
But:

```
object.apply();
==
for(int i=1; i < n; ++i) i.print();
```

Are not valid expression in Java (some are valid statements, but this is not what I'm looking for).

Is there a simple solution? (like `isJavaIdentifierStart` and `isJavaIdentifierPart` when one wants to determine whether a string is a valid identifier)

Comment: This sounds like, in the general case, you are trying to build  a Java parser.

Comment: You can add the piece of code into a class, write it to a file and compile it.Java 9 will have a REPL so I expect it will be simpler.

Comment: It could help http://javaparser.org/

Comment: [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) -  [Java parser](https://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/download/contrib/grammars/java-1.7.jj) - hack it. There's no support straight into the jsdk api for what you want.

Comment: Opposed to a valid java expression in C?

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the expression the same way the Java compiler would parse it, following the Java language standard specification.

Building your own parser from scratch is not a good idea; the Java syntax has gotten complicated in the last decade.  You should find an existing Java parser and reuse that so you don't have to reinvent the wheel incorrectly.

JavaCC and ANTLR are both available in Java-form, and have Java grammars defined for them.  I suggest you consider them as prime candidates.  A complication is that these parsers parse full programs, not expressions.  You can fix that by modifying the grammar to make expression a goal rule, and then fixing any grammar conflicts that may produce; I would not expect much.

A more complex issue: just because the syntax is valid, doesn't mean the expression is valid.   I'm pretty sure that the syntax of java will accept:

```
  "abc" *  17.2
```

as valid *syntax*.

If you want to verify the *validity* of the expression, you have to  *type-check* it, using the context in which the expression will be evaluated to provide the background type information.   Otherwise one will accept this as valid:

```
 s * d  // expression that parses correctly, but isn't valid
```

when the background knowledge is this:

```
 Object s;
 char d;
```

Doing a full type check is much, much harder.  As a practical matter, you'll need a full Java compiler front end, which parses and does the type checking.
Parser generators (e.g., ANTLR, JavaCC) provide zero help doing this.

So you either use the Java compiler or search for a Java front end; there are a few.  [Full disclosure: my company provides one that can do this].

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is definetly not a simple way to check whether a String is a valid Java code. I can think of only two ways.

**1. Export to a file and complie it**

You can save a String as a file with the `.java` suffix and compile it. According the result of compilation, you can said if the String is valid or not.

**2. Java parser**

You may find a library able to do that. Take a look at [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/). Here I cite from their site:

> A parser generator is a tool that reads a grammar specification and converts it to a Java program that can recognize matches to the grammar.

Comment: Second approach is simpler. Because you won't need to filter out reference resolving problem.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of a "valid Java expression" is ... rubbery.

For example:

```
  1 == true
```

is syntactically valid, but a Java compiler would reject it because `==` cannot be used with operands with that have those types.  Then:

```
  x.length() == 42
```

may or may not be valid, depending on the declared type of `x`.

---

If you are simply interested in whether an expression is syntactically valid, then a parser for a subset of the Java language is sufficient.

On the other hand, if you want to check if the expression would be compilable when embedded into a Java program, then the simplest approach is to embed the expression in an equivalent context and compile it with a real Java compiler.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a parser with [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

and you can define your own rules.